# Where is [super init] method actually located?

Tags: objective-c

Where is [super init] method actually located and what happens if we negotiate calling super init method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on entirely on the superclass.  If your class derives from `NSObject`, then it calls the `-init` method in the `NSObject` class.  If your class derives from the class `ParentClass`, then it calls the `-init` method in `ParentClass`.

Not sure what you mean by "negotiate" calling the super init method.

Comment: Thanks Adam and sorry for my vocabulary. The second one was what will happen if we don't call [super init], will the object initialize or not?

Comment: No it doesn't. You **need** to call super's init.

Comment: @Yuji:  Actually, I believe the *current* implementation of NSObject's init method just returns self.  So you can in theory get away with not sending init to super if you inherit directly from NSObject.  However, there is nothing to stop Apple from changing the implementation in the future, so although you can get away with omitting it, you should not omit it.

Comment: Indeed. I guess the commitment between us and Apple is that we call super's init (or other `init...`) and assign it to `self`. In principle Apple can change the implementation so that `alloc` always is a no-op and `init` does everything and return an alloc'ed object...